# Symfony Service has multiple instances

Tags: php, symfony

Why is the constructor of my service called after each request? I only want it to execute once for the lifetime of my application.

I expected my service's constructor to only be run once during the lifetime of my app because of [the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html) that states:

> $mailer = $this->get('my_mailer');
>
> As an added bonus, the Mailer service is only created once and the
>   same instance is returned each time you ask for the service. This is
>   almost always the behavior you'll need (it's more flexible and
>   powerful), but we'll learn later how you can configure a service that
>   has multiple instances.

However, when I call the service I am given a new instance. This happens for each request.

Possible Similar Posts

- [symfony2 service is not a singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9961999/symfony2-service-is-not-a-singleton?rq=1)

Comment: Is your mailer maybe defined in `scope: request`? If so, it will be created for each request (master request, and subrequest alike). So if you have service defined in `request` scope and you have {{ render(controller('...')) }} somewhere in your view for example, it will be actually instantiated twice (assuming it's needed in both request handling processes).

Comment: @Igor No. I think the problem is because I have a Java background. I expected the class to live in memory between requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means it's the same instance from the Request to the Response. If you call it during that lifetime it will return the same. If you call it in another Request it will give you a new object.

This is how PHP works, at the end of the execution, everything is freed from memory and every data and object is destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

> As an added bonus, the Mailer service is only created once and the
>   same instance is returned each time you ask for the service.

This does not mean that your service will be instanced once and for all until the end of time :)

It means that your service will be a singleton during the execution of your script. Basically, during the execution of your page/command.

If in your controller's action you call your service 4 times and you did not set the option `scope="prototype"` in you service definition then it will be instanced only once, as a singleton.

But it you change page and execute a different action in your controller that also calls your service. Php starts a new process, hence your service will be instance as a new object.